# TypeScript Enum with string value iterate, get only the keys, not the values

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to make an enum that has a string as a value and the goal is to iterate through only the keys in order to get the value but when I use the Object.keys method, it's also returning the values which is not what I want. Here's an example to prove my point.

Here's my example:

```
enum School {
    Denver      = <any>"Denver School",
    Wyoming     = <any>"Wyoming High School",
    Michigan    = <any>"Michigan Junior High",
}
const stringKeys = Object.keys(School).filter(x => isNaN(parseInt(x)));
console.log('the actual keys:');
for (const key of stringKeys) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the values as well as the keys as such:

```
the actual keys:
Denver
Denver School
Wyoming
Wyoming High School
Michigan
Michigan Junior High
```

Is there a way through actually iterate through only the keys? Note, that my project is on ES2015, not ES2017.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm receiving only 3 keys. See playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/KYOwrgtgBAygxgCwPZIDZQN4Cgq6gEVADdgAnPPAXigCJCQTz5k0aAaHPAdQE8kIAliADmFKNRq9+Q0QAkBwhLEQpU7TrgCyAxAoCGIChO27hBqACkwIAUnLzF6gL5Y4SEAGcALlG+kZANLAPB7iUADyAEYAVsBwXgB0ANbBHgAUzKoAlAkAZgKoXmRpAB7iAHxQAh4Acno1aQAOeqQewACSIF6lWb0A3K7uHmjACahIwmkA5F4IwFB68WB66CkhAFxTWQO5dlBpbp4+a1BIub5e-iJBIVmYGlCHw6ij45Nr21hOQA

Comment: Is there any reason to use `<any>`? I don't think it is even valid in enum value

Comment: @captain-yossarian You're right. I tried it with your example and it does indeed work. I'm wondering if it's because in the project that I'm using it, we're using "es2015" not "es2017" and the typescript website is using the 2017 version maybe? Also for the <any> use, it was recommended on a stack overflow post that I now can't seem to find so tried with/without it without any success. Our project is so big that I don't want to change the es version, I'm scared that it will break things.

Comment: Click on TS config in TS playground. You will see that you can change target. It still works as expected with es2015. I think it might be a problem with some babel plugin but it is only a guess

Comment: As for the using of `<any>` in place of enum values - I dont think it is a good idea. I don't even undarstend the benefit. Btw, which version OF TS do you use?